# Extend ListItem C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listitem

How can I extend `ListItem` class for add some attribute to it like this:

```
public class MyListItem : ListItem 
{
    public string Icon { get; set;} 
    public string Value { get; set;} 
    public string Text { get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: As per above lines of code your mylistitem had one property icon, what does Listitem class contain?can you be precise on the word extend,what do you wanna achieve here?

Answer (score 4):

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem` is a sealed class, so you cannot inherit it